# why we should write all these steps to generate a key for DES algorithm using java

Tags: java, cryptography

I need to understand why we should write all these steps to generate a key for DES algorithm using java:

```
DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
SecretKey secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
```

can anyone explain?

Comment: Because it designed in this way. Because Date mutable. Because...

Comment: You can also do it in one single line: `SecretKey secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(key));` but it doesn't exactly improive readability :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a line by line analysis:

```
DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key);
```

The above statement wraps a key represented as an array of 8 bytes as a KeySpec.  A KeySpec is described as "a (transparent) specification of the key material that constitutes a cryptographic key".  Transparent means you can look inside it.

```
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
```

The above statement gets a key factory for handling secret keys.  In this case, we are asking for a factory that understands DES keys.

```
SecretKey secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
```

The above statement turns the transparent form of the DES key into the opaque form.  Opaque means that you cannot see inside it.  Or at least, you can't without using reflection methods with access controlled by the sandbox SecurityManager.

---

Now I don't know the real reason for the `SecretKey` versus `KeySpec` dichotomy.  It could be to make sandboxing easier, or it could just be a slight case of over-design.  Or something else.

The purpose of using a factory here is to allow applications to mix-and-match crypto technologies.  Obviously, your code sample hard-wires a specific technology (DES), but the factory approach comes into its own when (for instance) a higher level protocol (e.g. TLS) needs to support multiple crypto algorithms.

The purpose of the `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(...)` call is clear too.  It is to avoid any explicit code dependencies on the actual classes that implement Java crypto.  This has to be done because those classes are in a separate JAR file that may or may not be present in your JRE ... as mandated by US export law.

Answer (score 1):

Because it was designed using the [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Their goal (can be wrong):

> The client does not know (or care)
>   which concrete objects it gets from
>   each of these internal factories since
>   it uses only the generic interfaces of
>   their products. This pattern separates
>   the details of implementation of a set
>   of objects from their general usage.

Comment: im so sorry i still donot understand the purpose of secretkey ,SecretKeyFactory and generatekey.

Comment: why i dont call some function and give it a key as a paramater.. why all these steps?

Comment: i tried to read the description of each class..but i dont know how differentiate and how to get it

Comment: One, because not every cryptographic algorithm uses the same parameter. This design is better as we only want the `SecretKeyFactory` of the cryptographic method we want (without worrying of additional parameters)...